# how to stop a thread in a threadpool

Tags: java

I'm writing an application that spawns multiple concurrent tasks. I'm using a thread pool to implement that.

It may happen that an event occurs that renders the computations being done in the tasks invalid. In that case, I would like to stop the currently running tasks, and start new ones.

My problem: How do I stop the currently running tasks? The solution I implemented is to store a reference to the task thread and call `interrupt()` on this thread. In demo code:

```
public class Task implements Runnable {

    private String name;
    private Thread runThread;

    public Task(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runThread = Thread.currentThread();

        System.out.println("Starting thread " + name);
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                System.out.println("Hello from thread " + name);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // We've been interrupted: no more messages.
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        runThread.interrupt();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And the main method is:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    Task t1 = new Task("Task1");
    Task t2 = new Task("Task2");
    executorService.execute(t1);
    executorService.execute(t2);
    executorService.execute(new Task("Task3"));
    executorService.execute(new Task("Task4"));

    try {
        Thread.sleep(12000);
        t1.stop();
        System.err.println("Stopped thread " + t1.getName());
        Thread.sleep(8000);
        t2.stop();
        System.err.println("Stopped thread " + t2.getName());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is this a good solution, or is there a better way to stop a running thread in a thread pool?

Answer (score 5):

You can stop it by holding a reference to that future

```
Future<?> future = exec.submit( new Runnable() {
    while (true){
        try{
            obj.wait();
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("interrupted");
            return;
        }
    }
});
future.cancel(true);
```

boolean is for - may interrupt if running.

I tested out and got an interrupted exception from that thread.

If you have cachedThreadPool you may want to double check that you catch the exception in your runnable, and then don't set back the flag interrupted, because your thread will run another future, if you set interrupt, the other queue future may not run.

Answer (score 4):

The idea behind your approach is one of the several correct solutions. [Dealing with InterruptedException](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/) gives a great rundown on how you should use the interrupt mechanism. This mechanism is mainly useful when you are long computations. One other thing to keep in mind is that it is possible for other libraries to spoil your interrupt mechanism by not doing what the guide says (not resetting the interrupt state when they haven't handled it etc).

Do note that your `Task` class isn't thread-safe. You could be stopping the task before saving the `currentThread`, which would give a NullPointerException.

A much simpler approach is to set a `volatile boolean` variable `running` and instead of a `while(true)` loop doing a `while(running)` approach (this is however much more general).

Another thing to look at is the `FutureTask` mechanism, as this already has a canceling mechanism that uses the interrupt mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

In your overridden `run()` method you loop forever with `while(true)`. The standard behaviour would be to have a `boolean runIndicator` which the `run()` method sets to true when it starts, and your loop should then be `while(runIndicator)`. Your `stop()` method should simple set `runIndicator = false` so the next iteration of the loop will fall out.

Comment: In this implementation, the `stop()` method should also call `this.interrupt()`.  In the actual implementation, there should be a similar method that you can use to stop whatever heavy lifting is going on instead of the `Thread.sleep*(4000)` call.  You can use a very similar method to the `runIndicator` to accomplish this.

Comment: @Erick, `interrupt()` isn't a method of runnable, so this isn't possible. `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` wouldn't work either because the calling of stop() happens in another thread than the one you want to interrupt.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch this.  I always extend `Thread` instead of `Runnable`, so I always have access to these things.  I would do the same here.  This would also solve the minor threadsafe issue you posted in your answer.

Comment: Good point on the thread safety. The advantage of using `Runnable` is that you can submit the jobs to the `ThreadPool` and therefor maximize the number of threads this is executed on. This will lower the performance costs (Threads are fairly expensive to use) and if you use a `ThreadPool` with only one thread you can be sure that the task that is submitted first is also finished first.

Comment: @Thirler A Runnable submitted to a thread pool will only ever be executed by one thread. Also, tasks are started in the order they are submitted, but that doesn't necessarily mean they'd finish in that order.

Comment: @Qwerky That is correct, but you can make ThreadPools (or executor services) that only contain one task. In that case only one task is running at the same time, the others are waiting for it to finish. This is very useful when implementing a FIFO mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

executorService.shutdown() and executorService.shutdownNow() should be used to shutdown the thread pool to gracefully exiting the application. See [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

See Qwerky's answer for ending the currently running thread.

Comment: That answer is given by Qwerky. But shuting down the thread pool is also required to gracefully exiting the application.