# Python ThreadPoolExecutor threads not finishing

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, sqlalchemy

I have a script for crawling a page using concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor using Python 3.8.2. Essentially it crawls a page for links, stores them in sqlite using sqlalchemy, and then moves on to the next page.

I have an issue however that the script never finishes. I have made sure that all processes are finished using two print statements, but the script just hangs and never finished. Is there something I have missed regarding how to deal with concurrency and the sqlite sessions?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


def crawl(link):
    print('Starting: {}'.format(link))
    session = Session()
    html = requests.get(url, timeout=10)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

    links = [entry.get('href') for entry in soup.find_all('a',  clazz)]
    for link in links:
        data = {
            'type': self.type,
            'status': self.status,
            'url': link
        }
        if not session.query(exists().where(Table.url == link)).scalar():
            d = DataEntry(**data)
            session.add(d)
            session.commit()

    print('Finished: {}'.format(link))

def main():
    links = ['www.link1.com', 'www.link2', ....]
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        the_futures = [executor.submit(crawl_for_listings, task) for task in tasks]
        for future in the_futures:
            try:
                result = future.result()
            except Exception as e:
                print('Thread threw exception:', e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine = create_engine("sqlite:///database.sql")
    Base = declarative_base()

    class Links(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'links'

        url = Column(String, primary_key=True)
        type = Column(String)
        status = Column(String)

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    Session = scoped_session(session_factory)

    main()

    Session.remove()
```

Comment: I'd recommend checking out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777772/how-to-stop-a-thread-in-a-threadpool

Comment: How is `tasks` now defined? Perhaps you should show more of your code.

Comment: That was just me writing wrong, it should be links. It is just a list of strings that I want to extract listed urls from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `submit` should be:

```
future = executor.submit(crawl, link)
```

Not:

```
executor.submit(crawl(link))
```

In the first case you are passing to `submit` a reference to a function and its arguments. In the second case you are first calling the function and then passing to `submit` the return value from that call, which appears to be `None`. You should then save the returned `future` object and you can test for the completion of the threads as they occur thus:

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor: 
    the_futures = []
    for link in links:
        future = executor.submit(crawl, link)
        the_futures.append(future)
    for future in futures.as_completed(the_futures):
        #print(future.result()) # result is None in this case
        pass
```

Or more "Pythonically":

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor: 
    the_futures = [executor.submit(crawl, link) for link in links]
    for future in futures.as_completed(the_futures):
        pass
```

Also note that I am creating variable `executor` using a context manager so that any necessary cleanup is done when the block terminates (a call to `shutdown` is made, which will wait until all futures are completed, but I am explicitly waiting for the futures to complete before exiting the block).

If you cared that the results are returned in the order of creation (you wouldn't in this case since the results returned are always `None`):

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor: 
    for result in executor.map(crawl, links):
        #print(result) # None in this case
        pass
```

The above `executor.map` function is, however, not that convenient when you want to obtain all the results and it is possible that one or more of the threads might throw an exception because you will not be able to retrieve a result from a thread beyond the first one that threw an exception (even assuming you use a `try/except` block for getting the results). It's also more complicated to use when the function you are invoking takes something other than one argument. So in those cases it's probably best to use futures:

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor: 
    the_futures = [executor.submit(crawl, link) for link in links]
for future in the_futures:
    try:
        result = future.result() # could throw an exception if the thread threw an exception
        print(result)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Thread threw exception:', e)
```

And with all of the above, I am still not sure why your program did not terminate. One thing is sure: **You were not multithreading.**

Comment: Thanks for the input. You are right, this is new territory for me, so I likely have still mistakes. I still have the same problem though, and I am wondering if it has to do with the sqlalchemy sessions somehow.

Comment: I had commented that I thought the `session.close()` in `crawl` may have been the issue. But I have found examples of where that seems to be what is supposed to be done. The code looks correct based upon what I have found on the web (not my own personal experience). Do any of your threads fail with an exception?

Comment: But thinking about exceptions made me think about why *in general* (this doesn't necessarily address your issue) if there is a possibility of a thread throwing an exception why you are better off not using the `executor.map` function but should instead use `executor.submit`, which returns a `future`. I've updated my answer to explain this a bit.

Comment: Now I got it to work. It appears that the session.close() was the issue. At the very least my code runs through, I tried many iterations to be sure, and the data is added to my database. Very strange considering so many suggested to use session.close()...

Comment: I looked at examples and they seemed to use `session.close()`, which I initially questioned since when you do a `session = Session()`, i thought every thread is getting the same session object. See: https://copdips.com/2019/05/using-python-sqlalchemy-session-in-multithreading.html. **Way 1** code is using a session per thread and a *context manager* in function `thread_worker` that guarantees that before the function ends it will have first called `close` on the session. But **Way 2** code, which uses `scoped_session`, does not call `close`.